# Stretching Horizontal Radio Button In Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How to stretch the Horizontal Radio Button to Full Width.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  class="row_b"> 


 <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_0" value="0" checked="checked" />
            <label for="q2_0">C</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_1" value="1" />
            <label for="q2_1">s</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2_2" value="2" />
            <label for="q2_2">P</label>


    </fieldset>
```

CSS

```
.row_b .ui-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

Tried setting the above method for 3 Radio buttons after checking this link.. http://jsfiddle.net/6rCmY/1/ But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.row_b .ui-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
}
```

I changed the width parameter to 33% and they were shown correctly, after tested.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark as Answer for the other members (10x).

Answer (score 0):

You must make your inner container (**.ui-controlgroup-controls**) of .row_b (specifically when you apply jqm's data-role="controlgroup") to fill the whole screen width.

Therefore, try:

```
.row_b .ui-controlgroup-controls { 
    width: 100%; 
}
.row_b .ui-btn { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.3333%;
}
```

CSS3 alternative:

```
.row_b .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    width: 100%;
}
.row_b .ui-radio {
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    box-flex:1;
}
```